# SQL - Combining two queries into one query

Tags: sql

I have 2 queries.

For `table1`,

```
SELECT codesTable.code_id,COUNT(*) FROM table1,codesTable
WHERE table1.codeid=CodeTable.code_id 
AND table1.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND table1.recoverd_value IN (0,1) 
GROUP BY table1.code_id
```

For `Table2`

```
SELECT codesTable.code_id,COUNT(*) FROM table2,codesTable
WHERE table2.codeid=CodeTable.code_id 
AND table2.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND table2.recoverd_value IN (0,1) 
GROUP BY table2.code_id
```

Need to combine this as one query.

**Note**:

Result for 1st query: code_id and count of Table1 and

Result for 2nd query: code_id, count of table2.

Current output like code_id,count of table(1,2)

Comment: You need to show us the output you expect.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Combine - how? Show us some result for each query, and also the combined result. (Formatted text, please. No images, no links.)

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh Thanks. I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT code_id, SUM(counted)
FROM (
SELECT code_id,COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM table1,codesTable
WHERE table1.codeid=CodeTable.code_id 
AND table1.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND table1.recoverd_value IN (0,1) 
GROUP BY table1.code_id

UNION ALL

SELECT code_id,COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM table2,codesTable
WHERE table2.codeid=CodeTable.code_id 
AND table2.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND table2.recoverd_value IN (0,1) 
GROUP BY table2.code_id
) AS subq
GROUP BY code_id
;
```

Don't forget to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` because `UNION ALL` saves duplicates from both tables.

Comment: Perhaps you need to name the subquery. (Some dbms:es require it, others don't) Still upvoted.

Comment: @jarlh, thanks a lot! Always forget about this. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just use union for this operation where two tables will be combined excluding the duplicates. Code is Shown below.

```
(SELECT code_id,COUNT(*) FROM table1,codesTable
WHERE table1.codeid=CodeTable.code_id 
AND table1.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND table1.recoverd_value IN (0,1) 
GROUP BY table1.code_id)
UNION
(SELECT code_id,COUNT(*) FROM table2,codesTable
WHERE table2.codeid=CodeTable.code_id 
AND table2.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND table2.recoverd_value IN (0,1) 
GROUP BY table2.code_id)
```

Hope this clarified your doubt.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/20290233/nithish-kumar Thanks for the response. After using union I'm getting each value twice actually. For example,


1) 001    -   10

2)001     -   10

3)002    -   20

4)002     -  20

Comment: Try using the full join and coalesce the both tables you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

You may *union all* the required results from `table1` and `table2` then join this unioned query to `codesTable` as the following:

```
SELECT D.codeid, COUNT(*) CN
FROM
(
  SELECT codeid, type_no, recoverd_value
  FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT codeid, type_no, recoverd_value
  FROM table2
) D
JOIN codesTable T
ON D.codeid = T.code_id
WHERE D.type_no IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) AND D.recoverd_value IN (0,1)
GROUP BY D.codeid
ORDER BY D.codeid
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bxo1yJKP).

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/12705912/ahmed Thanks for the response. Query seems good but inaccurate result for this query. May I know the logic here? As per knowledge after getting the values from two tables then we are filtering based on type_no and recoverd_value . Need some clarifications. After select D.codeid it's from which table ?  after d JOIN what's the logic here ...
Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, the logic is to union/ merge the rows from the two tables and then join this unioned query with the codesTable.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add sample data of your input tables and the expected output, so I can test the query on that data and make the required fixes if needed?

Comment: In your question you used two joined queries with the same table, what I did is union the two different tables and then join them with codesTable.